# Multiple Inheritance (Styled Components)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Please see the code snippets below
Is it possible for components to be based on other styled components.

What I would like to do is `const HeaderDropDownLi = styled(DropDownLi, HeaderItem)`

DropDownLi and HeaderItem are based on a styled component called HorizontalListItem

what I'm currently doing is

```
const HeaderItem = styled(HorizontalListItem)`
    background: #ddd
`;

const HeaderDropDownLi = styled(DropDownLi)`   
    background: #ddd
`;
```

I tried to implement a wrapper so `const H = () => <DropDownLi><HorizontalListItem></DropDownLi>`

but it doesn't work that way and I eventually pass a children prop like

````
    <HeaderDropDownLi 
        onClick={() => onClick(value)} 
        className={activeTab===value ? 'active' : ''}>
        <Dropbtn>{value}</Dropbtn>
        <DropDownContent style={contentStyle}>
            {" "}
            {children}
        </DropDownContent>
    </HeaderDropDownLi>
)```
````

Answer (score 11):

I think you can solved using "css" and exporting a baseStyle and then using it in your components.

```
import styled, { css } from ‘styled-components’;

const baseStyles = css`
  background: #ddd
`;

const HeaderItem = styled(HorizontalListItem)`
  ${baseStyles}
`;

const HeaderDropDownLi = styled(DropDownLi)`   
  ${baseStyles}
`;
```

Comment: How would you pass props to the ${baseStyles}?

Comment: @mondi Checkout their docs and look for the css helper (mixin): https://styled-components.com/docs/api#helpers